# ERROR 1111. Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select DEPT_NO from EMPLE group by DEPT_NO having count(OFICIO) = (select max(count(OFICIO)) from EMPLE group by DEPT_NO)
```

El objetivo es el siguiente, tengo que visualizar el departamento que tenga más empleados cuyo oficio sea 'EMPLEADO'.
Mi trozo de código es el introducido arriba, y me aparece el error mencionado en el título, ¿Es posible realizarlo de esa manera solucionando algo o es estrictamente necesario usar este otro código?:

```
select DEPT_NO, count(*) from EMPLE group by DEPT_NO order by DEPT_NO desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te paso la solución:

```
SELECT dept_no FROM emple
  WHERE oficio='empleado' GROUP BY 1
  HAVING COUNT(*)=(
    SELECT MAX(n) FROM (
        SELECT dept_no,COUNT(*) n FROM emple
          WHERE oficio='empleado' GROUP BY 1  
      ) c1  
  );
```

Me temo que ninguna de las soluciones que aportas es correcta, fíjate que en ninguna seleccionas a los empleados cuyo oficio sea empleado.

Incluyo el código de la tabla a la que haces referencia:

```
CREATE TABLE emple (
  emp_no INT(11) NOT NULL,
  apellido VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  oficio VARCHAR(30),
  dir INT,
  fecha_alt DATE,
  salario INT,
  comision INT,
  dept_no INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (emp_no)
);

INSERT INTO emple VALUES
(7369, 'SÁNCHEZ', 'EMPLEADO', 7902, '1990-12-17', 1040, NULL, 20),
(7499, 'ARROYO', 'VENDEDOR', 7698, '1990-02-20', 1500, 390, 30),
(7521, 'SALA', 'VENDEDOR', 7698, '1991-02-22', 1625, 650, 30),
(7566, 'JIMÉNEZ', 'DIRECTOR', 7839, '1991-04-02', 2900, NULL, 20),
(7654, 'MARTÍN', 'VENDEDOR', 7698, '1991-09-29', 1600, 1020, 30),
(7698, 'NEGRO', 'DIRECTOR', 7839, '1991-05-01', 3005, NULL, 30),
(7782, 'CEREZO', 'DIRECTOR', 7839, '1991-06-09', 2885, NULL, 10),
(7788, 'GIL', 'ANALISTA', 7566, '1991-11-09', 3000, NULL, 20),
(7839, 'REY', 'PRESIDENTE', NULL, '1991-11-17', 4100, NULL, 10),
(7844, 'TOVAR', 'VENDEDOR', 7698, '1991-09-08', 1350, 0, 30),
(7876, 'ALONSO', 'EMPLEADO', 7788, '1991-09-23', 1430, NULL, 20),
(7900, 'JIMENO', 'EMPLEADO', 7698, '1991-12-03', 1335, NULL, 30),
(7902, 'FERNÁNDEZ', 'ANALISTA', 7566, '1991-12-03', 3000, NULL, 20),
(7934, 'MUÑOZ', 'EMPLEADO', 7782, '1992-01-23', 1690, NULL, 10);
```

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda. Es cierto, me dejé el oficio = 'EMPLEADO', pero aún así me daba mal. La única duda es ¿por qué el group by 1?, es decir, ¿qué significa?

Comment: Ese 1 se refiere a que agrupe por el primer campo que proyectas justo después del SELECT, también serviría en el ORDER BY. Es muy cómodo porque evitas tener que escribir dos veces el nombre el campo y acortas un poco el SQL. Me alegra haberte ayudado, ánimo con el SQL, yo también aprendí con esta tabla...